# jqGrid  custom button with record values as parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to implement a custom EDIT button in [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start). This button needs to take the ID of the currently selected row and pass it to a new page (let's assume `edit_record.php`).

I have my custom button defined as:

```
.navButtonAdd("#pager",
    {caption:"Edit", 
    buttonicon:"ui-icon-newwin", 
    onClickButton:function() {
        // here is where I need a little help!
    }, 
    position: "first", 
    title:"Edit Property", 
    cursor: "pointer"
})
```

I just need a little help with the code for the function. I have found the following in another posting.

```
var grid = $("#customer_list");
var rowid = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
window.location = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'dataUrl');
```

But I can't quite get it right for forwarding to edit_record.php...

Comment: Sorry, but I not really understand your problem. Which URL you want to use? Just "edit_record.php" or "/edit_record.php" or something like "/edit_record.php?id=32&oper=edit"? Which parameters has your "edit_record.php" page? In the example from which you included the code example there are hidden column 'dataUrl' which had the full url which should be used to the row. The information about the url in your case should be get from another source.

Comment: Hi Oleg. I want to go edit_record.php andpass the record id either via POST or GET (POST preferred as that is the way the rest of the grid is functioning). I realise the example includes a hidden column, but this is not a column I am using. So, I want to have my custom button forward to the edit_record.php page and pass the record id in the POST variable... does that make sense?

Comment: OK, i have tried replacing the last line of the example with 'window.location.replace("edit_record.php?id=".rowid);' but Iit directs to a url ending in /false... what am I doing wrong??

Comment: @Oleg - in response to your question I want to use "edit_record.php?id=32&oper=edit" as the target url for my custom button. Appreciate any help you can offer... Si

Comment: @Simon S: Is `window.location="edit_record.php?id="+rowid+"&oper=edit"` is not what you need?

Comment: Oh hell. This is what comes of writing PHP and JS simultaneously. I am ashamed to say that I had the correct code, but was using a period as the concatenation operator, inseat of a '+'... will immediately administer a severe thrashing upon myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by Oleg, all I needed inside my custom button function is:

```
window.location="edit_record.php?id="+rowid+"&oper=edit"
```